# JavaScript function that process both single element selected by ID and multiple elements selected by class

Tags: javascript, element

I would like to write a JS generic function that can process indifferently a single element selected by its ID or multiple element selected by class.

```
var el1 = document.getElementById('myId');
myFunction(el1)
var el2 = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
myFunction(el2)
```

My problem is to write the function. I started something like:

```
function myFunction(el) {
    if (typeof el == undefined) process(el);
    else {
        for (let i=0 ; i<el.length ; i++)
            process(el[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm not really confident in this solution:

- not sure about the test (`typeof ... == undefined`)
- not sure about the loop, `map` should probably be a better option

Since this should be something commonly used, I'm convinced that some of you has already think to the best way to write this code.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably just accomplish this via a wrapper for the [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function, which is a built-in function used to easily query the DOM:

```
function myFunction(selector) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(`#${selector}`) || document.querySelectorAll(`.${selector}`);
}
```

This will return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of the matching elements (first checking for a given `id` attribute and if that fails, attempting to find any elements sharing the same name as a `class` attribute).

So if you wanted to perform some process, you could simply throw an iterator on the result if one exists and perform it against each element:

```
function myFunction(selector) {
     let nodes = document.querySelectorAll(`#${selector}`) || document.querySelectorAll(`.${selector}`);
     if(nodes) {
         for (var i = 0, i < nodes.length; i++) {
             process(nodes[i]);
         }
     }
}
```

### Example

```js
function myFunction(selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(`#${selector}`) || document.querySelectorAll(`.${selector}`);
}
```

```html
<div id='id'>id</div>
<div class='class'>class</div>

<br />
<button onclick='alert(myFunction("id"));'>Find By ID</button>
<button onclick='alert(myFunction("class"));'>Find By Class</button>
```